# ...что значит по-гречески — «побеждающий народ». Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, интонация

Господь даровал им сына, который при святом крещении получил имя Николай, что значит по-гречески — «побеждающий народ».

- Если нужно, то как обосновать? Интонационное тире?

Comment: Побеждающий народ — народ-победитель. А имя Николай = побеждающий народы, или победитель врагов.

Comment: Из Интернета: Имя Николай (нар. Никола, прост. Миколай и Микола) происходит от древнегреческого имени Николаос (ника - победа, лаос - народ) и означает: победитель народов, побеждающий народ, победа людей.  По-моему, лучший вариант - победитель народов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Господь даровал им сына, который при святом крещении получил имя Николай, **что  по- грЕчески значит —  "побеждающий народ".**

Или без тире: Господь даровал им сына, который при святом крещении получил имя Николай, **что  по-гречески значит «побеждающий народ».**

**Тире интонационное**, кроме того, желательно **переставить слова**, чтобы сделать паузу и более удобную расстановку логических ударений.

Их словаря: ЗНАЧИТЬ,  нсв. 1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать (о словах, знаках, жестах и т. п.). **Имя Виктор значит победитель**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В примере из словаря нет кавычек: Имя Виктор значит победитель. Это допустимо по нормам?

Comment: Думаю, что  в вашем примере употребление кавычек связано с тем, что они относятся к словосочетанию, а не к слову.